# Filter dates before today

Tags: excel, vba

I found and edited code. It is supposed to filter column O and only show dates less than or before today. Cell AC2 shows the date today. I can't even run the code.

```
With Sheets(1)
MyVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Sheets(1).Range("AC2").Value)
Sheets(1).Range("A1:AA1").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="<=" & MyVal
```

Comment: Have you declared the variable myval?

Comment: "I can't even play the code" is not a useful problem description. What is the specific problem you're having with the code you've posted?

Comment: Hi Ken,         
I'm trying to filter the column O that shows the data with invoices before today(date).

Comment: Hi Kory,

No not yet. Even though I declared the variable a while ago, it didn't allow me to play the code. 
Anyway, I've fixed that and can play the code now, trying to filter column O, as what I've mentioned with Ken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the below should do the trick. It will filter to show only dates before the current date, whenever the code is run, according to your computer's system time:

```
Sub DateFilter()
Sheets(1).Range("A1:AA1").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="<" & Date
End Sub
```

If you want today to be included, change "<" to "<=". "Date" is the VBA way to refer to the current date. It uses your computer's system time.

The WorkDay function is used to find a date a certain number of workdays after another date. You use it like this:

WorkDay(Starting Date, Number of Workdays to Count)

So, if you wanted to filter Column O based on, say, anything before the date five workdays after a date given in cell AC2, you could use:

```
Sub Datefilter()
Dim MyVal As Date
MyVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Range("AC2").Value, 5)
Sheets(1).Range("A1:AA1").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="<" & MyVal
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Liza,       
     Now the code has been played but it shows error on this line---
MyVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Range("AC2").Value, 5)

Comment: And yeah you're right. You understood my question correctly.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I left out the declaration statement there. Add "Dim MyVal As Date" before "MyVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Range("AC2").Value, 5)."

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Test()

Dim MyVal As Date

MyVal = Range("AC2").Value

ActiveSheet.Range("A:O").AutoFilter 15, ">=" & CDbl(MyVal)

End Sub
```

Comment: Please format Your code and explain why it should help.

Comment: +1 Upvote: In non-English Excel versions a comparison with a datetime value doesn't work, but an additional typecast to `CDbl` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

> This will allow you to filter column for < today's date even if your working with non US excel

```
Private Sub C_Out_of_date_Click()
Dim dDate As Date

Dim strDate As String

Dim lDate As Long

'Sheets("supplier") is a engine page where you can place info and then hide the tab 

 'sheets("Suppliers").Range("F1") = year (cell format yyyy) (=today() in cell) 

 
'Sheets("Suppliers").Range("G1") = month (cell format mm) (=today() in cell) 



'Sheets("Suppliers").Range("H1") = day (cell format dd) (=today() in cell)


dDate = DateSerial(Year(Sheets("Suppliers").Range("F1")), month(Sheets("Suppliers").Range("G1")), day(Sheets("Suppliers").Range("H1")))


lDate = dDate

Sheets("MHRA").Range("$A$1:$G$1353").AutoFilter

                                        'change field depending on your data cloumn
Sheets("MHRA").Range("$A$1:$G$1353").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<" & lDate
end sub
```

> hope this helps

Comment: Please, describe the solution. A code listing with no comments is not useful because it's hard to learn something from it.

Comment: hi its in the title of the answer, with this code you can use it to filter a set of date with less than todays date which is good if you have a lot of stock with Expiry dates and you want a quick overview of things that have expired

Answer (score -1):

Can try filter date for example after which date.
Field, 7th column.

> ActiveSheet.Range("A:G").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">" & CLng(CDate("12/31/2015")), Operator:=xlAnd

Comment: Please do not post identical answers to multiple questions without tailoring them to the individual questions.

Answer (score -1):

```
LL = Cells(1000000, "G").End(xlUp).Row 'last cell in column g
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LL, 7)).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(Date - 3)
```

Comment: Instead of just posting some code, some amount of explanation will add value to understand the answer.